# C# Backgroundworker not reporting progress

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Going off of this... https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/841751/MultiThreading-Using-a-Background-Worker-Csharp, I'm trying to have my program do some work in the background on a separate BackGroundWorker.  The operation works very well with the exception that `myWorker_ProgressChanged` does not update the label `lbl_status_totalFilesNotCurrent.Content` when called from within the `myWorker_DoWork` foreach loop `sendingWorker.ReportProgress(cnt);`  Im not able to figure out why this part isn't working per the codeproject example.

follow up question... Is the background worker the preferred method for this sort of task, or should i be using tasks? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming.  Im starting to get the sense that background worker is deprecated.

```
private BackgroundWorker myWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        currentUser.name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        lbl_IndProj.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(changeFontColor);
        lbl_IndProj.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(resetFontColor);

        myWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(myWorker_DoWork);
        myWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        myWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(myWorker_ProgressChanged);
        myWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        myWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!myWorker.IsBusy)
        {
            myWorker.RunWorkerAsync(currentIndex);
        }
    }

    protected void myWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker sendingWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        Index ci = (Index)e.Argument;
        int cnt = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Project> project in currentIndex.projects)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, IndexedDirectory> directory in project.Value.IndexedDirectories)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, IndexedFile> indexedfile in directory.Value.IndexedFiles)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        List<IndexedFile> ood = currentIndex.getOutOfDateIndexedFiles();
                        if (ood.Contains(indexedfile.Value))
                        {
                            cnt++;
                            indexedfile.Value.extractInfo();
                            lbl_status.Content = indexedfile.Value.LongName;
                            sendingWorker.ReportProgress(cnt);
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_status_totalFiles.Content = currentIndex.getAllIndexedFiles().Count().ToString();
        lbl_status_totalFilesNotCurrent.Content = currentIndex.getOutOfDateIndexedFiles().Count().ToString();
    }

        protected void myWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int cnt = e.ProgressPercentage;
        int report = currentIndex.getOutOfDateIndexedFiles().Count() - cnt;
        lbl_status_totalFilesNotCurrent.Content = report.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: `catch { }`, is `ReportProgress` ever called?

Comment: Have you tried: `lbl_status_totalFilesNotCurrent.Dispatcher.Invoke()` instead ?  I'm guessing that your event handler code is not executing on the UI thread. Best way to find out is to breakpoint the event handler code and in the debugger's thread view, ascertain which thread this is running on. If not on the UI thread, you **must** run the `Dispatcher.Invoke`, otherwise, nothing good will happen, LOL.

Comment: Create the instance of the `BackgroundWorker` on the `UI` thread as `ProgressChanged` will raise events on the thread that created the instance.

Comment: It is the kind of code, especially when you run it repeatedly, that causes the 3rd most common threading bug.  A *firehose* bug.  Where the worker thread floods the UI thread with work to do, faster than it can accomplish.  It starts burning 100% core trying to keep the UI updated and stops taking care of lower priority duties.  Painting and responding to user input.  Only update UI at a rate of no more than 25 times per second, any faster is wasted effort on the user's eyes.

Comment: @HansPassant I cann't find any definition about firehose bug, what's that? tnx

Comment: It is English idiom, google "drinking from a firehose".